# Why is “D” the Center of “Attention” at this Circular Conference

Tags: mathematics

All the Alphabet Guests are seated according to their order at a unit distance apart around this circular conference table.

Why is “D” the center of “Attention”?

[image: circular alphabet table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks UVC for confirming my comment!

> There are 26 letters each a unit distance apart from the neighboring ones. If they are
> considered to be point sized, the circumference is $26$ units and $26$ divided by $2π$ is
> $$\frac{26}{2π}≈4.138≈4$$
>  and the fourth letter is **D**. Thus **D** is the center of "ATTENTION".

Comment: So the radius is approximately 4, D is the 4th letter, how does that link to “ATTENTION”?

Comment: @NeilW Center of attention means a thing of concern and here it's D, which corresponds to the radius.

Comment: D=4...r=4...he is connected to all the alphabet guests by being in the center..garnering “attention”from everybody

Comment: That is way too much of a stretch.